# How do I check if a particular value in a series of values has already been added to XML prop?

Tags: regex, tcl, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Consider

```
set data {<prop>red;blue;green</prop>}
```

I can add a new color using

```
  incr count [regsub -all -- \
      [appendArgs (< $name >)(.*?)(</ $name >)] $data [appendArgs \
      \\1 $newValue \\3] data]
```

where newValue is defined by

```
set newValue [join \
    [list \\2 [string map [list \\ \\\\] $value]] $separator]
```

if value is "pink", I'll end up with

```
<prop>red;blue;green;pink</prop>
```

If I run it again, I get

```
<prop>red;blue;green;pink;pink</prop>
```

Is it possible to rewrite the regex to check for $value and only add it if it is missing? Also, it should be able to handle

```
<prop>red;blue;pink;green</prop>
```

I tried ((?!$value)) but it didn't really work. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc addToContent {data color} {
    lassign [split $data <>] -> tag content endtag
    if {$color ni [split $content \;]} {
        return "<$tag>$content;$color<$endtag>"
    } else {
        return $data
    }
}

addToContent {<prop>red;blue;green</prop>} pink
# -> <prop>red;blue;green;pink</prop>
addToContent {<prop>red;blue;pink;green</prop>} pink
# -> <prop>red;blue;pink;green</prop>
```

If your Tcl version doesn't have `lassign`, use `foreach {-> tag content endtag} [split $data <>] break`. If you don't have the `ni` operator, use `[lsearch -exact [split $content \;] $color] < 0`. In both cases, you should upgrade.

But for real XML processing you should use something like `tDOM`.

Documentation: [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [tDOM](http:///http:/tdom.github.io)